# Cannot create identity provider with nonexistent sitecore domain "ad"

Tags: configuration

I just built a local instance of Sitecore 10.1 and I was able to bring up an Instance of Sitecore 10.1. Then, I pointed my connectionStrings to my DEV environment and published my current Sitecore Site, which does work with Sitecore 10.1 but when I try to load Sitecore CMS 10.1 I am now receiving this error:

```
Cannot create identity provider with nonexistent sitecore domain "ad"
```

How do I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore support helped me with this since everything in the installation was out of the box. The support expert had me update the `FederatedAuthentication.config` file in the `app_config/include` in the Sitecore-edit root. I changed the domain under *IdentityProviders* from "ad" to "sitecore". and now I am able to authenticate and bring up Sitecore with my content.